# How do I get a property of an object in an array of those objects in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nslog

I have an array of custom objects, but I can't NSLog the property of an individual object in that array because you can store any objects in an array. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Are all the objects in your array of the same type?  If so, can't you cast the object and access whichever property you need?

Comment: Casting is not necessary in Objective-C, as it's Runtime offers a decent degree of introspection.

Answer (score 6):

Objective-C offers several [introspection techniques](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Introspection.html) trough it runtime system.

You can ask a object, if it is from a certain kind, or responses to a certain message.

```
for (id anObject in array ){
    if([anObject isKindOfClass:[MyClass class]]){
        MyOtherClass *obj = anObject.myProperty ;
        NSLog(@"%@", obj);
    }
}
```

and

```
for (id anObject in array ){
    if( [anObject respondsToSelector:@selector(aMethod)] ) {
        NSLog(@"%@",[anObject aMethod]);
    }
}
```

As properties usually results in synthesized methods, the second way should also work for them.

Also to mention — although not in the scope of this question:

Classes can also be ask, if they fulfill a certain protocol. And as Objects can tell there class, this is also possible:

```
[[anObject class] conformsToProtocol:@protocol(MyProtocol)];
```

Answer (score 2):

The above answer is correct for accessing individual fields.  Just as a side note, there are also some interesting tricks that you can do with key-value path coding and *Collection Operators* when you have a collection like an array.  For example, if you have a large array of objects with a small number of values for one field:

```
 NSArray *allObjects;
```

you can create an array with all of the unique values of one of your fields with the statement:

```
 NSArray *values=[allObjects valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.myObjectsInterestingProperty"];
```

or you can find the average value of a field with the statement:

```
 NSNumber *average=[allObjects valueForKeyPath:@"@avg.myObjectsInterestingProperty"];
```

All of the other key-value path Collection Operators you can use this way are listed in [Apple's Key-Value Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html)